# ESP8266 Serial Communication with ATMega328P

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, atmega328

I am isolating the ATMega328P from the Arduino Uno. I have used it for many other projects, so it does work as intended. Also, I have used my ESP8266-01 for other projects and works great (including serial communication).

I am trying to get the ESP8266-01 to make the ATMega328P pin 13 blink an LED. That is all.

When the ESP8266 is hooked to the TX/RX of the arduino board, the program works exactly as intended. I hook it up the exact same way to the ATMega328P and it doesn't work.

I am using baud rate of 9600 for the communication and using a 16MHz crystal for the ATMega328P.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTWCDi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The controller is getting 3.3v from the supply as well. And pin 13 is supposed to turn on/off depending on the serial value. Below is the code for the ESP8266:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10000);
  Serial.write("LED ON");
  delay(10000);
  Serial.write("LED OFF");
}
```

And below is the code for the ATMega328P:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if(esp8266.available()) 
  {
    String command = "";
    while(esp8266.available())
    {
      command += (char)esp8266.read();
    }

    if(command == "LED ON") {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);  
    }

    if(command == "LED OFF") {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
  }

  delay(500);
}
```

As stated, they work great separately, but when I try serial communication with them together, it doesn't work.

P.S. I usually set my ESP8266 baud rate to 115200, but the ATMega328P, I believe, needs to run at 9600 because of the 16MHz clock frequency. Not sure about this part, though.

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNWGap.png)</sup>

Comment: "but the ATMega328P, I believe, needs to run at 9600". Its hardware UART is fully capable of 115200 baud and higher. The 9600 baud limitation applies to a SoftwareSerial port, which is simulated by programmed 'bit-banging' on another pair of digital I/O pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, try to debug the problem.  Evidently either you're not getting data from your `esp8266.available()` and/or `esp8266.read()`, or it's not the right data.  Put traces (`Serial.println(...)`) in, print things out, and find out what's going wrong.

---

Specifically, I suspect the issue here is that you are relying on all the data being available *immediately*: you check `esp8266.available()` which will tell you whether one or more bytes is available.  Then you `esp8266.read()` until there are no more bytes available.  What if there's a 1ms delay between bytes arriving?  You'll get,perhaps `LED O`, `esp8266.available()` will tell you there's no more data (there's not, *yet*!) and you stop reading.

You could probably get it working by putting a small `delay()` in:

```
while(esp8266.available())
{
  command += (char)esp8266.read();
  delay(100);
}
```

That's a solution (probably) but not a *good* one.  A better solution would be to make your commands `LED_ON\n` and `LED_OFF\n` - and read until you get a `\n`.

Comment: I tried the above and still no luck. I don't think that would be the issue because the code works with the atmega attached to the uno. All I truly did was isolate it from the uno and added the 16MHz crystal for the external clock.

Comment: I don't know then, sorry. What is *actually* going wrong? Have you put trace in to find out how far it's getting, where it's failing etc?

Comment: I put it back into the uno, and now it is not working. I may have messed up the controller. I will try with a new atmega.

Comment: Okay. It works perfectly with the uno. But when I take the controller off and set it up as shown above, it wont work.

Comment: Omg. I figured it out. I forgot to power the other side of the chip. wow.